# Pass structure with array to multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, structure

I have been desperately trying to pass a structure to multiple threads. The problem is I can't find the right format to pass it in the pthread_create function. It just won't work.
If have tried to pass pointers of my structure to pthread_create but it just won't work.
I have pointer assignements errors.

```
typedef struct thread{
   pthread_t thread_id;
   char *filename;
   int blocksize;
   int random_int;  
} ThreadData;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int nb_threads = atoi(argv[3]);
    int blocksize = atoi(argv[2]);
    int re;
    int index;
    char *name;
    char* mode = argv[1];
    int i = 0;
    ThreadData thread[nb_threads];
    int random_int;
    srand(time(NULL));  
    random_int = rand();
    index = detect_mode(mode);
    index_glob = index;

    for(i=0; i < nb_threads; i++){

        snprintf(name, 25,"temp%d",i);
        thread[i].filename = name;
        thread[i].blocksize = blocksize;
        thread[i].random_int = random_int;

        switch(index_glob){ 
        case 0:
            re = pthread_create(&(thread[i].thread_id),NULL,write_seq_file,(void *)(&thread[i]));
            break;
        case 1:
            re = pthread_create(&(thread[i].thread_id),NULL,write_ran_file,(void *)(&thread[i]));
            break;
        case 2:
            re = pthread_create(&(thread[i].thread_id),NULL,read_seq_file,(void *)(&thread[i]));
            break;
        case 3:
            re = pthread_create(&(thread[i].thread_id),NULL,read_ran_file,(void *)(&thread[i]));
            break;      
        default:
            exit(0);
            break;
        }
        if(re == -1){
            printf("Error creating thread %d / %d\n",(i+1),nb_threads);
        }
        else{
            printf("Thread %d / %d created.\n",(i+1),nb_threads);
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i< nb_threads; i++){
        pthread_join(thread[i].thread_id, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}

void* write_seq_file(void *thread){
    ThreadData *my_data = (ThreadData*)thread;
    char *filename = my_data->filename;
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename,"w+");
    int blocksize = my_data->blocksize;
    char c = 'a';
    long i;
    for (i=0; i<blocksize; i++){
        fputc(c,fp);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work, which kinds of errors you get?

Comment: '(void *)(thread[i])'  thread[i] is of type ThreadData. Not sure what casting that to void* does.  How about '(void *)(&thread[i])'?

Comment: This is  nowhere near *complete* code. Ex: What do you expect `snprintf(name, 25,"temp%d",i);` will do with an indeterminate pointer `name` ? And `index_glob` is nowhere to be found, yet assigned the value of `index`, assigned from `detect_mode()`, an unknown function. You seem to have some fundamental issues that need settling before attacking threading.

Comment: @WhozCraig - oh yes.  Look!  No malloc!  I assumed all that easier stuff was working - didn't even bother to check.

Comment: The thread function's return type shall be `void*`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Don't worry about index_glob and detect_mode, this is not the part I have problem with. All you have to know is detect mode return an int that I then pass to index_global.
What I ask is how to properly pass the structure to pthread_create.

Comment: @MartinJames With your solution I got "expected 'void* ( * )(void *)' but argument is of type 'void ( * )(void*)'"

Comment: @JahMyst I'm not worried about anything. But this is **clearly** not the **real** code in the **real** order as it presents in your source. For example, there is no way `write_thread_proc` can be passed as a thread-proc parameter to a `pthread_create` call as is done in this code without at least a function prototype declaration or the actual implementation existing *prior* to its use in `main()`. It is **vital** when having "this code doesn't work" issues the **real** code be presented **verbatim** so as to minimize the flailing of inapplicable answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite understand your program and I'm not sure whether this will run as you expect.
But;

Here are some points to get this to compile:

pthread_create expects a void *(*start_routine) (void *) as the worker function. Therefore change write_seq_file and all worker functions to the following format.

```
void* write_seq(void *thread)
{
  ...
  return NULL;
}
```

Your Thread data array is an array of objects. Not pointers. Therefore first acquire the address and cast it to void.

```
re = pthread_create(&(thread[i].thread_id),NULL,write_seq_file,(void *)(&(thread[i])));
```

Not sure whether exit(0) in the middle is a good idea. I'd rather use return 0; because the main function must return a value.

The following is not declared in the given code. So hopefully there are no problems there.

```
index = detect_mode(mode);
index_glob = index;
```

Make sure you have function prototypes declared before main or move the function implementation above main function.

Finally pthread_join expects a pthread_t thread as the first argument. There for the line should be changed as shown below.

```
pthread_join(thread[i].thread_id, NULL);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Once you've fixed these things... one caveat: you need to be very careful passing a pointer to 'automatic' data to a pthread.  It's fine if you are absolutely certain that the data will not go out of scope (and cease to exist) while the pthread is running.  That is true in this case... but in general, this is a good way to get yourself bitten in the backside.

Comment: I did what you proposed and I got the warning : "expected 'void* ( * )(void *)' but argument is of type 'void ( * )(void*)'"

Comment: @JahMyst that would be because you changed the function *implementation* to patter as `void *thread_proc(void*)`, but not the function *prototype*, which we conveniently are not shown in your posting (either included in a header file or somewhere above `main()`. They *both* need to be changed.